# Prevent download attempts of videos in a video server

Tags: java, streaming, video-streaming, red5

Any way to achieve this with Red5 and Flash player?

Right now this is theoretical only: I deliver streams with verification token that is dynamic for each video. Streams are over RTMPE. When a user asks for a stream, the server generates him a link to the stream with a unique token in it. He can watch it in the Flash player then. How can I verify that he's not downloading it? (After the user quits the Flash player page, the token is removed so he can't save the stream link forever). Does the RTMPE encryption + the temp-auth-token is enough? Maybe a way to allow only 1 user per a stream?

I don't have access to Hulu (Since I live outside of the US), but I'm sure they have some kind of this protection.

Notes:

- I'm not talking about analog screen capturing. I just want the original file to be safe.
- I know that there will be always a way to capture the stream. I just want to make it harder so only computer-pros will be able to do this.
- The solution needs to be applicable in Java, as the whole server tools I'm using is Java-only.
- Please don't say: "You can do that by not delivering the videos at all". I'm delivering the videos to almost any device, and when a user subscribe to the service -- he knows what he gets from the beginning. And I also understand it's not cool to ask devs and geeks this kind of question but I don't have a choice in this case.

Comment: you say *"I'm not talking about analog screen capturing"* but you're not talking either about *"digital screen capturing"*.  DVI sniffers exists and are quite cheap so capturing each digital frame is trivial if you have such a sniffer.  Sure, that would need re-encoding which is lame but it's still thousands times better than *"analog screen capturing"* and there's absolutely **ZERO** thing you can do versus someone having a DVI-sniffer.  Moreover some sniffers are 100% passive so there's no way to detect them.  Just pointing that out because you did mention "analog"...

Comment: Not on a desktop. How should the browser have any ideas or even worse stop it if I use fraps in the background? And then there's the simple fact that the browser already plays the video and most (at least ff/chrome) store the video in a temp folder..

Comment: @SyntxT3rr0r I know that the "pros" will always find a way to bypass this protection. I just want to make it harder.

Comment: @Voo Again, I don't care about this kind of tools (Screen recording tools), and I'm sure there's a way to disable the video caching.  All I want is the original video file to be download-protected.

Comment: @Ron: "Again"? You said you're not talking about analog screen recording, but fraps and co are digital. Anyhow, you can't get the browser to change its internal behavior just because you want to - what a gigantic security problem that'd be. And then it can't get much simpler than "copy file from xyz/tmp and rename". Also a "download protected file" doesn't make any sense - if you wouldn't allow downloading the file nobody could watch the video.

Comment: @Voo When I said "analog" I meant this kind of recording. Sorry for being unclear.  Anyway, as I originally thought -- I won't get this kind of question answered on geeks Website (I'm a geek too, of course :). I already have some code so I'll try to expand it in the coming days or weeks.

Comment: @Ron So when you said "analog" you meant "digital" :p Anyways, any solution you will come up with will be **trivially** circumvented by anyone capable of googling "download [flash] video" and being able to copy a file (or use one of the hundreds of tools for the job that'll turn up when googling) - both things even my parents are capable of.. If you need DRM, you can try silverlight, but that probably has problems with "java only solution"

Comment: I believe there's a way to do this kind of thing. I already have a solution to other devices, and as I said, I began working on the desktop solution. Again, I don't care if the user records his screen -- I just want to block the ability to download the original video file -- And I believe I found a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Once apon a time subscription users of netflix was able to download their movies. Now i believe netflix uses microsoft's silverlight technology to protect from downloading. Silverlight might be an idea to start with.

Comment: Thanks but no thanks. Can't integrate it with the rest of my infrastructure so it's not helping me.